# Angular2 formating text input into dd-MM-yyyy

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a form in my angular project that I send via json to my JAVA rest API, I need the date string to be in the dd-MM-yyyy format. How can I do this? I know you can use the date pipe to format it as output, but I need to format the value of the formControl string so I can send it as json. Any ideas?

Tried setting it as type="date" but it doesn't change anything

```
<ion-input formControlName="pacientedataexame" placeholder="Data do Exame:" type="date"></ion-input>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are more into ionic way of doing this rather than plain angular:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD-MM-YYYY" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

further reading you can find as usual in [ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? [Check This Reference](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime)

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" formControlName="pacientedataexame"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

---

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Time</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="h:mm A" pickerFormat="h mm A" formControlName="pacientedataexame"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```